# Table of 10 people meeting each other in groups of two

Tags: combinatorics

I want to create a table of meetings for 10 people meeting each other in groups of two people. Everyone should meet everyone, but only once!

For simplicity, the table should contain the names like A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J or 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.
This way A should meet first day B (A-B), second day C (A-C), third day D (A-D)... and so on, and on the nineth day would meet J (A-J). If I'm right 9 days would be enough to arrange all the meetings. I'm stuck with collecting the pairs for all these 9 days.
Can you please provide me the table with names for these meetings?

Thanks for your kind help!

Br,

Balu

Comment: This is just a round-robin tournament.  (Think of the people as competitors in an athletic contest, and each day as a round.) 
 I'm sure you'll be able to find instructions for scheduling one on the web.  https://nrich.maths.org/1443

Comment: Thank you! I could generate my table based on the Round-Robin Tournament algorithm! :)